# CMake: Passing two (or more) defines to Swig

Tags: cmake, swig, preprocessor

I have an issue with CMake's integration of SWIG, though, I'm pretty sure I just misuse lists/strings. I have a set of defines which need to be passed to Swig in order to exclude some optional c++ features. For instance, I have the two defines `foo` and `bar` and want them to be passed to Swig. For this purpose, I'm using `CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS` which allows me to set some Swig related options, `-Dfoo` and `-Dbar` in my example.

Since `foo` and `bar` may or may not be defined (depending on the actual build system) I need to calculate them at configuration time. Until now, I tried to use a simple string. That is, if some condition holds I add `-Dfoo` to the string. If another condition holds I add `-Dbar` as well (and so on). Let's say the string's name is `ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES`. The idea is to pass `ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES` to `CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS`, for instance,

```
set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS -package "somepackage" -O ${ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES})
```

If none of the defines has been set, `ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES` is empty.

Unfortunately, it looks like Swig is ignoring the second define if both of them has been added to `ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES`. Therefore, I tried to pass them directly with:

```
set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS -package "somepackage" -O -Dfoo -Dbar)
```

et voila, it works as expected. So my question is, How do I dynamically add my defines to some sort of variable and pass it properly to Swig? As already mentioned, I think this is more a miss-usage of CMake's strings than really an issue with CMake's integration of Swig.

EDIT: `ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES` is created as follows:

```
if(DOUBLE_PRECISION)
  set(ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES "${ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES} -DDOUBLE_PRECISION")
endif()
if(DISABLE_CXX11_FEATURES)
  set(ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES "${ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES} -DDISABLE_CXX11_FEATURES")
endif()
string(STRIP "${ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES}" ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES)
```

Comment: Can you show the CMake code which sets up `ADDITION_SWIG_DEFINES`? And BTW, your question uses both `ADDITION_SWIG_DEFINES` and `ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES`. Is this sorted out in your real code?

Comment: Updated question. Of courser there is only: `ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES`, that was a typo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS` is apparently a CMake list, so you should treat `ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES` as a list as well. But you're treating it as a single string instead. Basically, you were defining a macro named `foo -Dbar`.

Drop the quotes:

```
if(DOUBLE_PRECISION)
  set(ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES ${ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES} -DDOUBLE_PRECISION)
endif()
if(DISABLE_CXX11_FEATURES)
  set(ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES ${ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES} -DDISABLE_CXX11_FEATURES)
endif()
```

(Notice that the call to `string(STRIP)` is removed as well).

To be more obvious, you can also use `list()` syntax:

```
if(DOUBLE_PRECISION)
  list(APPEND ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES -DDOUBLE_PRECISION)
endif()
if(DISABLE_CXX11_FEATURES)
  list(APPEND ADDITIONAL_SWIG_DEFINES -DDISABLE_CXX11_FEATURES)
endif()
```

(The two code blocks I give are semantically equivalent).

Comment: "`CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS` is apparently a CMake list" I don't get how it can be _so_ poorly documented that this comes as a surprise to _**everyone**_ — but I'm glad it's not just me! Even in [the current docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseSWIG.html), there's _nothing_ that would ever make you suspect you should be using it as a list. Especially since trying to set e.g. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` as a list does **not** work.